# Entity Framework Core Set null one property of entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

I need to save a entity that implements baseEntity

If i modify IdStatus, efcore Update it correctly, but if idStatus value does not change on other props updating => for some reason efcore set it to null

idStatus = 20 => try to update to 12 => success

idStatus = 12 => try to update description => idStatus = null, desc ok

```
public void Update(TTableEntity updated, int userid)
    {
        toSave = GetById(updated.Idnrr);

        PropertyCopier<TTableEntity, TTableEntity>.Copy(updated, toSave);
                    //tosave.idstatus == 20 ! 
        toSave.DateMod = DateTime.Now;
        toSave.UserMod = (short)userid;

        _dbContext.Update(toSave);
        _dbcontext.SaveChanges();//after save => idstatus == null
    }
```

i'm on

- .net core 3.0 preview 6
- efcore 3.0 preview 7
- database first model creating
- i use baseManager with iBaseEntity as common crud manager (IBaseEntity has id, DateMod ,UserMod
- TTableEntity implements IBaseEntity interface
- error seems occur only on IdStatus (nullable smallint, short?), but it works fine with other "nullable smallint, short?" prop

**EDIT core version update**

EFCore updated to preview 9,

.Net Core 3.0 Updated to preview 9

Same Error

**EDIT:** updated obj does not have tracking so i need to take an istance of same obj then copy props to it => then save

before 'SaveChanges()' idstatus is still 20

**EDIT: PropertyCopier code**

```
public static class PropertyCopier<TSource, TTarget> where TSource : class where TTarget : class
{
    public static void Copy(TSource source, TTarget target)
    {
        var sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties();
        var targetProperties = target.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
        {
            var targetProperty = targetProperties.SingleOrDefault(x =>
                sourceProperty.Name.ToLower() == x.Name.ToLower() && sourceProperty.PropertyType == x.PropertyType);
            if (targetProperty == null)
                continue;
            var value = sourceProperty.GetValue(source);
            targetProperty.SetValue(target, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: example**
i tried to set toSave.IdStatus manually (no propCopier) with the same value saved in db (that means i don't want to change the value db.idstatus = 20 / tosave.idstatus = 20).After savechanges i have db.idstatus = null **(A)**

If i try to update again (null to 20 ) => success , db.idstatus = 20 **(B)**

**EDIT 2 for Seabizkit :**

```
public interface ISimpleEntity
{
    int Idnrr { get; set; }
}
*public interface IBaseEntity : ISimpleEntity
{
    short? UserIns { get; set; }
    DateTime? DateIns { get; set; }
    short? UserMod { get; set; }
    DateTime? DateMod { get; set; }
}
public partial class Tbl : IBaseEntity { }//i have to do this in other file
public partial class Tbl
{

    *public int Idnrr { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? endDate { get; set; }
    public short? IdStatus { get; set; }
    public byte? id2{ get; set; }
    public short? IdRequester { get; set; }
    *public short? UserIns { get; set; }
    *public DateTime? DateIns { get; set; }
    *public short? UserMod { get; set; }
    *public DateTime? DateMod { get; set; }
    //other 140 public props
}
```

**EDIT :"again"**

i tried to change status value from 20 to 12 => updated.status = 12, after propscopy tosave.status = 12 (before copy was 20) => SaveChanges() db.status = 12 OK, it works **(C)**

BUT

if i need to update some other value, or execute save again, after (C) (with updated.status=12 and db.status=12 ) => after propscopy toSave.status=12(event before) => saveChanges() db/tosave status prop becomes null **(D)**

image: debug of propCopier method for idStatus Prop => it works,even with other props and even with same/or not idstatus value **(A,B)**

TEST A it works (copy commented)
[image]

TEST B f*****k (copy not commented ) even if i set manually idstatus 
(tosave.idstatus = updated.idstatus)
[image]

Comment: you could add the code for the copy... this would help as the problem is most likely with your implementation of how you believe you are change/copying properties, rather than an issue with EF

Comment: - i don't think so, because if i change the idStatus to 12  the update method works
and
- after propCopy the idStatus is set correctly

Comment: interesting... could you include the full code for entity which represents [toSave]. include the full PropertyCopier class..

Comment: @Seabizkit here for you

Comment: this is probably a stretch as i am also struggling to see the issue but what happens if you switch the loops around, loop first over targetProperties and then inner loop the sourceProoperties

Comment: after the execution of propCopy the toSave.Idstatus value is stil 12

look at the "again" edit, example (C) update changed value works well....instead of save entity with status equal to db status (beforeSave) => save works well for all other props, but status become null

Comment: just notices `_dbContext.Update(toSave);` technically you shouldn't need this... as  `toSave = GetById(updated.Idnrr);` aka toSave should be a tracked entity, but again dont think this is to do with the issue you seeing.

Comment: you're right, but behave the same way, Same "null error"

Comment: Can you confirm that when debugging that the entity properties are correct just before savechanges...by loop through the entity proprieties and check their EF Status's as well that's what i would do to debug this.... too either confirm its EF or my code.

Comment: As you can see at the (A) example , to avoid "my code error", i manually set  (no propcopy) the id status prop with same value of db.idStatus , result after save => db.idstatus = null

Comment: ok i see, you  would need to check all setters of idstatus as that doesnt make sense. there most be some code somethere setting it to null, otherwise have you tried a different version of EF maybe 6.2 or 6.3 latest. or core stable.... i see you using core..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199418/discussion-between-massimiliano-acampa-and-seabizkit).

Comment: Nope, efcore preview 9 and .net core preview 9 -- 
Same ERROR

Comment: then i would say its defo an issue with your code, is there away i can get access to a copy, maybe a really slimmed down version which has the issue, host in GIthub or something, without seeing all the code, or well enough of what you are doing it, would be to hard to guess.

Comment: how can i provide you a small runnable project if solution/proj is related to my db (i can't provide the db )?

Comment: mmm gd question don't really have an answer... but you can not reproduce with a single table... in code first.. dnt really need the db... but need full context of the code. share code on git or something.

Comment: last 2 image added for you, it's annoying

Comment: i know its a pain but I've stared at your pic... to hard to confirm what is going on... make a quick git repo and add the code there... i will have a look at that. There is no reason why what you are trying to do should not work.... there is just something that is being missed.

Comment: You show your code setting `IdStatus` but you say `idstatus` is `null`. Can you confirm you're not actually looking at two differently cased members in your code? I would look at the generated SQL and see what's executed. Is `IdStatus`' column actually `null` after saving or only the `IdStatus` property? I agree the behavior doesn't make sense from what we can see and it would seem something else (other code, db trigger?)  is setting it to null. You might also try looking at the `toSave`'s `CurrentValues.PropertyNames` before saving to see if `Modifed` is true/false on the expected properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using

```
PropertyCopier<TTableEntity, TTableEntity>.Copy(updated, toSave);
```

and manually assign the properties of `updated` entity into `toSave` one by one.

Comment: it doesn't change, i tried to set toSave.IdStatus manually with the same value saved in db (that means i don't want to change the value db.idstatus = 20 / tosave.idstatus = 20) 
After savechanges i have db.idstatus = null 
if i try to update again (null to 20 ) => success , db.idstatus = 20

Comment: i added more example

Comment: this is not the answer to my problem , but it's ok